# Парсим xml с помощью php

Tags: xml, php

Пишу следующее:

```
function getMoneyCountry($cityName, $valRQ) {
    $requestAddress = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=".date("d/m/Y")."&date_req2=".date("d/m/Y")."&VAL_NM_RQ=".$valRQ;
    $xml_str = file_get_contents($requestAddress,0);
            $xml = new SimplexmlElement($xml_str);
    $count = 0;
        foreach($xml->ValCurs as $item) {
            foreach($item->Record as $new) {
                $money = $new->Value;
            }
        }
    return $money;
}
```

Ссылка получается например вида:

```
<ValCurs ID="R01700" DateRange1="31/01/2012" DateRange2="31/01/2012" name="Foreign Currency Market Dynamic">
<Record Date="31.01.2012" Id="R01700J">
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Value>17,0158</Value>
</Record>
</ValCurs>
```

Функция ничего не возвращает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml->ValCurs` вам не нужен. Разбирайте, начиная с `$xml->Record`.

**Добавлено**

```
$requestAddress = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp?date_req1=31/01/2012&date_req2=31/01/2012&VAL_NM_RQ=R01700";
$xml_str = file_get_contents($requestAddress);
$xml = new SimplexmlElement($xml_str);
foreach($xml->Record as $new) {
    $money = $new->Value;
}
echo $money;
```

Comment: Не помогло. Так же пусто.

Comment: Обновил ответ.